# SQL Count Entries Greater Than Date Including Zero Across Junction Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database consisting of 1 table of categories, and 2 data tables (photos and video titles)

The relationships of the 2 data tables to the category table (ie which photos and videos fall under each category) is maintained by 2 junction tables (photo_categories and video_categories)

This structure and some example data can be found here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/197c9/1

and is reproduced here:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(category_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE photos(photo_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, date_added TEXT NOT NULL, date_last_modified TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE videos(video_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, date_added TEXT NOT NULL, date_last_modified TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE photo_categories(photo_id INTEGER, category_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(photo_id) REFERENCES photos(photo_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
CREATE TABLE video_categories(video_id INTEGER, category_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(video_id) REFERENCES videos(video_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("Animals");
INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("People");
INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("Nature");
INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("Buildings");
INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("Vehicles");
INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES("Computers");

INSERT INTO photos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Man walking his dog", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01");
INSERT INTO photos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Bird sat on roof of house", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01");
INSERT INTO photos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Birds sat in a tree", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01");
INSERT INTO photos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Car outside house", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01");
INSERT INTO photos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Couple walking on beach", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01");

INSERT INTO videos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Horses running", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01");
INSERT INTO videos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Cars racing", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01");
INSERT INTO videos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Fish in river", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01");
INSERT INTO videos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Computer loading", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01");
INSERT INTO videos(title, date_added, date_last_modified) VALUES("Crowd cheering", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01");

INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(4, 4);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(4, 5);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(5, 2);
INSERT INTO photo_categories(photo_id, category_id) VALUES(5, 3);

INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(2, 5);
INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(4, 6);
INSERT INTO video_categories(video_id, category_id) VALUES(5, 2);
```

I have a query which produces a count of the number of photos, and a count of the number of videos under each category, including zero if applicable.  This works and is as follows:

```
SELECT
    photos_group.category_id,
    photos_group.title,
    photos_group.num_of_photos,
    videos_group.num_of_videos
from (
select
    categories.category_id,
    categories.title,
    count(photos.photo_id)
AS
    num_of_photos 
FROM
    categories
left JOIN
    photo_categories
ON
    (photo_categories.category_id = categories.category_id) 
left join
     photos
ON
    (photo_categories.photo_id = photos.photo_id)
GROUP BY
    categories.category_id
    ) photos_group
left join (
    select
categories.category_id,
    count(videos.video_id)
AS
    num_of_videos 
FROM
    categories
left JOIN
    video_categories
ON
    (video_categories.category_id = categories.category_id) 
left join
     videos
ON
    (video_categories.video_id = videos.video_id)
GROUP BY
    categories.title

    ) videos_group
    on photos_group.category_id = videos_group.category_id;
```

So with the example data above, this produces the correct result as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  category_id  |  title     |  num_of_photos   |  num_of_videos  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1    | Animals    |        3         |         2       |
|      2    |  People    |        2         |         1       |
|      3    |  Nature    |        2         |         1       |
|      4    | Buildings  |        2         |         0       |
|      5    |  Vehicles  |        1         |         1       |
|      6    | Computers  |        0         |         1       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to add a condition to this query, to count the number of entries (including zero) where the date_added and date_modified fields are greater than a value

For example, where these fields are >= 2021-01-1, the result should then return,

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  category_id  |  title     |  num_of_photos   |  num_of_videos  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1    | Animals    |        3         |         2       |
|      2    |  People    |        2         |         1       |
|      3    |  Nature    |        2         |         1       |
|      4    | Buildings  |        1         |         0       |
|      5    |  Vehicles  |        0         |         1       |
|      6    | Computers  |        0         |         0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I am not clear where to add the WHERE condition to ensure that the result table maintains the structure above but the counts are updated.

For example, if I try adding a WHERE clause before the GROUP_BY of each SELECT, the count is incorrect and also doesn't include zero counts, and places a null where there is a result from the photos but not the videos:

```
SELECT
    photos_group.category_id,
    photos_group.title,
    photos_group.num_of_photos,
    videos_group.num_of_videos
from (
select
    categories.category_id,
    categories.title,
    photos.date_added,
    count(photos.photo_id)
AS
    num_of_photos 
FROM
    categories
left JOIN
    photo_categories
ON
    (photo_categories.category_id = categories.category_id) 

left join
     photos
ON
    (photo_categories.photo_id = photos.photo_id)
  where
    photos.date_added > 2020-05-01
GROUP BY
    categories.category_id
    ) photos_group
left join (
    select
categories.category_id,
    count(videos.video_id)
AS
    num_of_videos 
FROM
    categories
left JOIN
    video_categories
ON
    (video_categories.category_id = categories.category_id) 
left join
     videos
ON
    (video_categories.video_id = videos.video_id)
where   
  videos.date_added > 2020-05-01
GROUP BY
    categories.title

    ) videos_group
    on photos_group.category_id = videos_group.category_id
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  category_id  |  title     |  num_of_photos   |  num_of_videos  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1    | Animals    |        3         |         2       |
|      2    |  People    |        2         |         1       |
|      3    |  Nature    |        2         |         1       |
|      4    | Buildings  |        2         |      (null)     |
|      5    |  Vehicles  |        1         |         1       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any guidance on how I can achieve my desired result would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: drive from categories and left join sub queries.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon - are you be able to give any more details on this approach, or an example?

Comment: I just noticed that the link is to a sqllite fiddle not mysql as the question is tagged  - what are you actually using?

Comment: Apologies - I'm using sqlite format 3.  I have removed the erroneous tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date_added field is a text field, so you need to put quotes around the date you are comparing. Also you want to start with a select of all the categories, then left join that to the photo search and the video search. Finally, you can use ifnull to replace nulls with zeroes.

```
SELECT
    cats.category_id,
    cats.title,
    ifnull(photos_group.num_of_photos, 0) as num_of_photos,
    ifnull(videos_group.num_of_videos, 0) as num_of_videos
from (
  select category_id, title from categories
) cats
left join
(
  select category_id, count(photos.photo_id) as num_of_photos from photo_categories
  left join photos using (photo_id)
  where photos.date_added > "2020-05-01"
  group by photo_categories.category_id
) photos_group
on (cats.category_id = photos_group.category_id)
left join (
  select category_id, count(videos.video_id) as num_of_videos from video_categories
  left join videos using (video_id)
  where videos.date_added > "2020-05-01"
  group by video_categories.category_id
) videos_group
on (cats.category_id = videos_group.category_id)
```